# How to convert a semantic version shell variable to a shifted integer?

Tags: shell, math, version, posix, string-math

Given a shell variable whose value is a semantic version, how can I create another shell variable whose value is *(tuple 1 × 1000000) + (tuple 2 × 1000) + (tuple 3)* ?

E.g.

```
$ FOO=1.2.3
$ BAR=#shell magic that, given ${FOO} returns `1002003`
# Shell-native string-manipulation? sed? ...?
```

I'm unclear about how POSIX-compliance vs. shell-specific syntax comes into play here, but I think a solution not bash-specific is preferred.

---

**Update:** To clarify: this isn't as straightforward as replacing "`.`" with zero(es), which was my initial thought.

E.g. The desired output for `1.12.30` is `1012030`, not `100120030`, which is what a `.`-replacement approach might provide.

---

Bonus if the answer can be a one-liner variable-assignment.

Comment: which shell is that? bash, zsh, ksh... are all different and can result in significantly different code

Comment: @phuclv - I believe that I cannot assume which shell. Most likely bash...but can't say for sure.

Comment: @StoneThrow : You basically have 2 separate problems: (1) Cutting `FOO` into its constituents (1, 2, 3) , and the multiplying the constituents (i.e. you need integer arithmetic). Right? So these are two sub-problems, and if you are stuck with one of them, ask a question only for this particular problem, and also show your own attempt.

Comment: @stoneThrow : Most likely bash...but can't say for sure .... Sorry, but this is insane. You want to write a program, but don't are not sure which programming language you want to use? Make up your mind first about this. Different languages will possibly lead to different solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A perl one-liner:

```
echo $FOO | perl -pne 's/\.(\d+)/sprintf "%03d", $1/eg'
```

How it works:

- `perl -pne` does a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) with the supplied program
- The program contains a replacement function `s///`

  - The search string is the regex `\.(\d+)` which matches a string beginning with dot and ends with digits and capture those digits
  - The [`e` modifier of the `s///` function](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Modifiers) evaluates the right-hand side of the `s///` replacement as an expression. Since we captured the digits, they'll be converted into int and formatted into leading zeros with [sprintf](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf)
  - The `g` modifier replaces all instances of the regex in the input string

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/SJMJTa_Pu)

Comment: Nice. Can you offer an explanation on how that works? By experiment, it delivers the required result. And I assume the use of Perl mitigates problems about POSIX-compliance. But I can't readily decipher how that one-liner is doing things like "multiply by 1000000" or "multiply by 1000" as is needed to get the required answer format.

Comment: @StoneThrow added some explanation

Comment: Am I correct to say that by using Perl, we avoid any concern about POSIX-compliance of the variable-assignment syntax (like my answer below that uses bash arrays)?

Comment: @StoneThrow sorry I'm not a language lawyer and I don't know where to read in that huge standard. In practice it seems all systems I've had access does have perl by default

Answer (score 1):

Split on dots, then loop and multiply/add:

```
version="1.12.30"

# Split on dots instead of spaces from now on
IFS="."

# Loop over each number and accumulate
int=0
for n in $version
do
  int=$((int*1000 + n))
done

echo "$version is $int"
```

Be aware that this treats 1.2 and 0.1.2 the same. If you want to always treat the first number as major/million, consider padding/truncating beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
echo $foo | sed 's/\./00/g'
```

Comment: Close! I was thinking of something similar, but not quite right. This is substituting `.` with `00` which is slightly different than the required output.  
E.g. given `1.12.30` this returns `100120030`, which is different than the required output of `1012030`.

Comment: Here's a revision that stops short of calculating: `echo $foo| awk -F. '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {print $i*1000^(NF-i)"+"}}'`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$ ver=1.12.30
$ foo=$(bar=($(echo $ver|sed  's/\./ /g')); expr ${bar[0]} \* 1000000 + ${bar[1]} \* 1000 + ${bar[2]})
$ echo $foo
1012030
```